# The provided antiforgery token was meant for a different claims-based user than the current user

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I'm rolling my own auth system and only using the bits that I need. My solution is based on [this github repo](https://github.com/leastprivilege/AspNetCoreSecuritySamples). I've reviewed similar questions, but they don't seem to fit my situation. I also read [this post about Authentication and JWT](https://stormpath.com/blog/token-authentication-asp-net-core), but I'm not sure if that's relevant or not either. I'm lost.

My Startup.cs:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationScheme = "Cookies",
            AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
            AutomaticChallenge = true,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/auth/login")
        });

        app.UseClaimsTransformation(context =>
        {
            if (context.Principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                context.Principal.Identities.First().AddClaim(new Claim("now", DateTime.Now.ToString()));
            }

            return Task.FromResult(context.Principal);
        });
```

My Auth Controller works as expected. Here is my login action which uses [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]; however, the entire Controller is set to [AllowAnonymous]:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel viewModel, string returnUrl = null)
    {
        ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var result = await _userManager.LoginUserAsync(viewModel.UserName, viewModel.Password, viewModel.RememberMe);
            if (result.Success)
            {
                // TODO: Log successful login

                var claims = new List<Claim>
                {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, result.User.FullName),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, result.User.Email)
                };

                foreach(var role in result.User.Roles)
                {
                    claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role.Name));
                }

                var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "password");
                var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

                await HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync("Cookies", principal);

                return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                AddModelErrors(result);
                return View(viewModel);
            }
        }

        // Doh!
        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

So far, so good.

Here's where I get the error (400 Bad Request). in the Create (Post) method:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public class UserAdministrationController : Controller
{
    private readonly IUserManager _userManager;
    private readonly IUserAdminViewModelFactory _userAdminViewModelFactory;

    public UserAdministrationController(
        IUserManager userManager,
        IUserAdminViewModelFactory userAdminViewModelFactory
        )
    {
        _userManager = userManager ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(userManager));
        _userAdminViewModelFactory = userAdminViewModelFactory ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(userAdminViewModelFactory));
    }


    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var userViewModels = _userAdminViewModelFactory.CreateUserViewModelList();
        return View(userViewModels);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        var createUserViewModel = _userAdminViewModelFactory.CreateUserViewModel();
        return View(createUserViewModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult Create(CreateUserViewModel viewModel)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Actually, the method never fires due to this error:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.AntiforgeryValidationException: The
>   provided antiforgery token was meant for a different claims-based user
>   than the current user.
>          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.Internal.DefaultAntiforgery.ValidateTokens(HttpContext
>   httpContext, AntiforgeryTokenSet antiforgeryTokenSet)
>          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.Internal.DefaultAntiforgery.d__9.MoveNext()

I don't receive the error if I remove the [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]; however, I still receive the error if I remove the [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")] attribute.

I imagine I've "messed up some mundane detail" or something, but not sure where.

Comment: Are you logging in with an AJAX request? If so, you'll need to refresh the page containing the AF token after a successful login, because the token would initially be generated for the anonymous user, and you're no longer that user once you've logged in.

Answer (score 3):

Try to set the user before the antiforgery token is build, since the antiforgery token is build using the user claims.

```
...
await HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync("Cookies", principal);
HttpContext.User = principal;
...
```